# Which is easier for human perception: type of variable before or after its name?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

In some programming languages type of variable goes before it's name.
In another - name goes first and then type.
Which version loads brain less and allow easier think about problem ?

Comment: I think that your question is off-topic here. It is rather pure cognitive psychology.

Comment: @Evil There are empirical studies under the aegis of CS of questions of this sort, e.g. is `for` or `repeat` a better keyword. I would lean towards them being on-topic, though the question would need a more quantifiable metric, e.g. bug count or number of hours to complete a standardized task. No one cares if your brain is loaded more or less if you produce correct code quicker, though presumably those are (negatively) correlated.

Comment: @DerekElkins I am reading papers now, just under the Cognitive Psychology aegis. The pure perception and brain load is rather off here. And honestly it makes sense when the group is defined (not programming, beginners, experts), where for experts it does not make any sense. My point is, that the "brain load" is cogPsy, while the other reasons are for example given at [SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/316217/why-does-the-type-go-after-the-variable-name-in-modern-programming-languages). "No one cares if your brain is loaded more or less" - psychologists do...

Comment: “the integer a” is easier to read than “the a which is an integer”

Comment: related on [softwareengineering.SE]: [Why does the type go after the variable name in modern programming languages?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/316217/66652) (also specific questions about [Kotlin](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/311727/66652) and [Scala](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/264509/66652)) - no empirical studies but good arguments

Comment: @tmlen That probably depends on your mother tongue

Comment: @tmlen one could as well argue the opposite direction: “a is an integer” is easier than “the integers contain a”.

Answer (score 7):

I don't *think* there is any research (with good methodology) on this. The language I'd most expect to have actually thought about this and made an empirically-based decision is the [Quorum programming language](https://quorumlanguage.com/evidence.html). It uses a "type before variable name" approach (though it does put the *return type* of a method declaration after the parameter list). However, what I believe is the primary source for the language design decisions, [An Empirical Investigation into Programming Language Syntax](https://doi.org/10.1145/2534973) (available via the [first author's web site](http://web.cs.unlv.edu/stefika/research.html)), does not mention this aspect or suggest that it was studied in the research reported on in that paper. There is other research by that group and research by others that was used to design Quorum, so it's possible it *is* covered in that other research. I haven't read it all. You can try contacting one of the creators of Quorum and asking them if they made that decision based on empirical research. If you do and you get a positive response, I would highly recommend self-answering this question with a reference to the research.